# Strange behaviour of knockout visibility binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My problem is rather strange. I use `ko.observable()` to set visibility of loading indicator on page like this:

```
<img src="/images/loader.gif" data-bind="visible: isLoading"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
self.processExcelData = function(data, event) {
        self.isLoading(true)

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.someBigArray(), function(item){
            // continuous stuff
        })

        self.isLoading(false)
}
```

The problem is that although `isLoading` is actually `true` while `arrayForEach` iterates but loader is shown only after `arrayForEach` is finished.

Comment: Doesn't that need to be `data-bind="visible: isLoading()"`

Comment: @artm Either will work.  If you're binding to an observable, it's fine to leave the brackets off.

Comment: @Andy J, out of curiosity, is the element invoking the `processExcelData` method `<a>` or `<button>`/`<input>`?

Comment: @haim770 , `<a>` element invokes `processExcelData` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that while the JavaScript is running, the browser doesn't have a chance to re-render any updates.  You need to delay the processing to allow knockout to update and the browser to re-render the DOM.  You can do this using `setTimeout`:

```
self.processExcelData = function(data, event) {
    self.isLoading(true)
    setTimeout(function() {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.someBigArray(), function(item){
            // continuous stuff
        });
        self.isLoading(false)
    }, 0);
}
```

Using `setTimeout(fn, 0)` in this way causes the code within `fn` to be moved to the end of the execution queue, allowing the browser to render any updates needed.

Comment: This might still not show the loading image if it isn't preloaded I think

Comment: @sroes Yes, that's true.

Comment: This fixed my problem partially. The loader is a gif image and while arrayForEach goes on gif animation also stops. But this seems a kind of browser perfomance issue, not javascript. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyJ. Yes, webpages and the javascript they contain are single threaded, meaning that whenever javascript runs, the UI will freeze.  If the processing is that intensive, perhaps consider using a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) - they run on a background thread